# How do I use C#'s IndexOf when strange characters are in the string

Tags: c#, indexof

Below is what the text looks like when viewed in NotePad++.

[image]

I need to get the IndexOf for that peice of the string. for use the the below code. And I can't figure out how to use the odd characters in my code.

```
int start = text.IndexOf("AppxxxxxxDB INFO");
```

Where the "xxxxx"'s represent the strange characters.

Comment: What's the problem? "I'm lost" isn't very informative.

Comment: It strikes me that you haven't got a *text* file to start with. Where did this come from?

Comment: It's a Borland Database configuration file. IDAPI32.CFG to be specific.

Comment: What about this? `var searchString = "App" + '\0' + (char)0x01 /* SOH */ + '\0' + (char)0x03 /* ETX */
  + '\0' + '\0' + '\0' + "DB INFO";`

Comment: @Chris: Yuck.. Just use hexadecimal character escapes: `"App\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00DB INFO"`

Comment: @JonSkeet: probably a mixed textual/binary file (like for instance `.wav` that has text as well) opened in a text editor.

Comment: Right, so if it's not a text file, don't try to read it as text. It's bound to cause issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these characters have corresponding [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/), you can insert them in a string by escaping it.

For instance:

```
"App\x0000\x0001\x0000\x0003\x0000\x0000\x0000DB INFO"
```

or shorter:

```
"App\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00"+"DB INFO"
```

`\xXXXX` means you [specify one character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) with `XXXX` the hexadecimal number corresponding to the character.

*Notepad++* simply wants to make it a bit more convenient by rendering these characters by printing the abbreviation in a "bubble". But that's just rendering.

The origin of these characters is printer (and other media) directives. For instance you needed to instruct a printer to move to the next line, stop the printing job, nowadays they are still used. Some terminals use them to communicate color changes, etc. The most well known is `\n` or `\x000A` which means you start a new line. For text they are thus characters that specify *how to handle text.* A bit equivalent to modern html, etc. (although it's only a limited equivalence). `\n` is thus only a new line because there is a consensus about that. If one defines his/her own encoding, he can invent a new system.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the NotePad++ explanation. I tested your example and it works great. Thank you!

Comment: "hexadecimal number corresponding to the character," the _character_ being a [Unicode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF)/UTF-16 code unit, not a ASCII codepoint.

Comment: @TomBlodget: the first 256 unicode numbers are ascii numbers. And all the characters in the question are ascii ones. In that sense unicode is an extension of ascii where one uses 16 bit instead of 7.

Comment: True enough but ASCII is not relevant to the C# language. The specification doesn't even contain the word "ASCII."

Comment: @TomBlodget: the specs say "*`\x hh`: ASCII character in hexadecimal notation*". Now the question contains only ascii characters like `nul` (sometimes used to end a string),... Your answer speaks of data corruption. First of all one does not modify the data, so there is no corruption. Secondly as specified in the answer, codes below `0x20` are generally used to format text in a terminal. So strictly speaking they are metacharacters. Otherwise `\n` would also be non-text... There is no clear distinction between text data and binary data. It's only how to interprete the bits...

Comment: Oops, you're on the Microsoft's C Reference (and that should say ANSI, not ASCII).

Comment: @TomBlodget: Well this is [C#'s page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) indeed speaks of unicode characters. Thus the compiler adds a zero byte in front of a `\x` followed by the byte in hex. But that's not relevant, if one uses `zram` there is much chance they will get encoded by Lempel-Ziv in memory. The characters originate from ASCII and you can specify them as noted in the answer. How they are encoded is up to the compiler. If in the future one invents his/her own encoding, you only need to modify the way you parse string literals...

Answer (score 1):

Echoing @JonSkeet's warning, when you read a file into a string, the file's bytes are decoded according to a character set encoding. The decoder has to do something with bytes values or sequences that are invalid per the encoding rules. Typical decoders substitute a replacement character and attempt to go on.

I call that **data corruption**. In most cases, I'd rather have the decoder throw an exception.

You can use a standard decoder, [customize one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or create a new one with the Encoding class to get the behavior you want. Or, you can preserve the original bytes by reading the file as bytes instead of as text.

If you insist on reading the file as text, I suggest using the 437 encoding because it has 256 characters, one for every byte value, no restrictions on byte sequences and each 437 character is also in Unicode. The bytes that represent text will possibly decode the same characters that you want to search for as strings, but you have to check, comparing 437 and Unicode in this [table](http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP437.TXT).

Really, you should have and follow the specification for the file type you are reading. After all, **there is no text but encoded text**, and you have to know which encoding it is.

Comment: Thank you. I'm learning so much here. But I'm only planning on reading the file and not writing to it. Shouldn't this be OK? Thanks again for the info!

Comment: Yes, reading incorrectly will not change the file. It'll just give the wrong answer.